# Unicode white space issue in j2me

Tags: java-me, jsr75

I have made an app in j2me which uses unicode characters to display my language. i.e. Urdu. Everything works fine expect the issue that it adds some extra spaces at the start of the string, my language is Right to left, it works fine over Nokia mobiles as I think they adjust such issue by OS, but in samsung mobile with a bit less resolution and features it raises that issue. I have tried to remove spaces though but vain. I have added Image along with this post to give you an idea. The string should have been in center while its not. Thanks!
its a bit blurry but thats what I got.

[image: Red circle shows spaces]

Comment: How are you drawing that String? Are using LWUIT? LCDUI Canvas?

Comment: I am using simple unicode characters, an algorithm to convert English alphabets into my language on the basis of phonetics ....

Comment: Have you tried to call String.trim after convert English alphabet into your language?

Comment: yeah a number of times, there's no problem in code, I tried to hardcode it, it works fine for English conversion but for my language it looks like above